# How to use FormView in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried using the FormView in Django from the sites
[godjango](https://godjango.com/16-class-based-views-part-2-listview-and-formview/) and [formview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCIQAvwtIfc&list=PLQCgNGUqLK4lxXqo8j-Nru0YJ9llISeAx)
but do not know why it did not work.

See my code:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from models import Contato
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

#class ContatoForm(UserCreationForm):
class ContatoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contato

#views.py
# encoding: utf-8

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, FormView
#from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from teste.models import Contato
from teste.forms import ContatoForm

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('teste/index.html')

class index2(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'teste/index2.html'

class Lista(ListView):
    template_name = 'teste/lista.html'
    model = Contato
    context_object_name = 'nomes'

class Criar(FormView):
    template_name = 'teste/formulario.html'
    form_class = ContatoForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.request.POST['nome'])
        return super(Criar, self).form_valid(form)


#urls.py
# encoding: utf-8

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from teste.views import index2
from teste.models import Contato
from teste.forms import ContatoForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='teste/index.html')),
    url(r'^index2/$', index2.as_view()),
    url(r'^lista/$', 'teste.views.Lista'),
    url(r'^formulario/$', 'teste.views.Criar'),
    #url(r'lista_marca/$', 'carros.views.listaMarca', name='lista_marca'),
)

#formulario.html
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Criar" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

See my project on the [github](https://github.com/rg3915/django/tree/master/templateview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the [as_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

`url(r'^formulario/$', Criar.as_view()),`